# GRPC Server getting Client cancellation

Tags: java, server, netty, grpc, grpc-java

i have created a microservice for a webcam-stream with grpc. the streaming works fine but the cancellation of the stream works only on client side.

if the client calls CancellableContext.cancel, the streaming of video stops but the server is still streaming a video with the cam. if the cancellation is called the server throws a Transport faild Exception.

could this exception can be catched for stopping streaming or other operations on the server-side?

```
ClientCall<KameraStreamRequest, KameraStreamResponse> call = (ClientCall) imageStreamBlockingStub.getChannel().newCall(ImageStreamServiceGrpc.METHOD_IMAGE_DATA_STREAM, imageStreamBlockingStub.getCallOptions());
call.sendMessage(KameraStreamRequest.newBuilder().setStreamState(StreamState.STOP).build());
```

The streaming is started with a simple request which has an enum with State.START. if i call the code above to change the state to STOP i become an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not started
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:174)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.sendMessage(ClientCallImpl.java:388)
at org.cpm42.grpcservice.ImageStreamClient.cancelStream(ImageStreamClient.java:70)
at org.cpm42.main.StreamClientMainClass.main(StreamClientMainClass.java:21)
```

i have read that this could be a bug.

is it possible to get Sessions or Connections or something else on server-side?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be a slightly different problem, but for a simple client/server project I needed to add: `channel.shutdown().awaitTermination(5, SECONDS);` to the client method making requests to get rid of the Exception.

```
io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport notifyTerminated
SEVERE: Transport failed
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the 
remote host.
```

What does the rest of your stacktrace say?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps. But you could try on the server side to poll the gRPC Context if the call has been cancelled and act accordingly:

```
import io.grpc.Context;
{ ...
    Context.current().isCancelled()
 ...}
```